# c++ Finding the length of a char pointer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that reads in a "string" (into a char *) from user input, then using cstring, it gets the length of what the char * is pointing to. From what I understand, char * is a pointer. A reference to a pointer will be redirected to what it is pointing to. In this case, word should point to 4321, and when word gets output, what it is pointing to is what actually gets output. Also, strlen should read up until the \0, which in this case the string should be 4321\0, so why does it segmentation fault?

Desired result:

```
Enter a string: 4321
4321
(length of 4321)
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *word;
    int len;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> word;

    len = strlen(word); //why does this cause a segmentation fault?

    cout << word << endl;
    cout << len << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `word` so it contains garbage pointing to some random location in memory. You tried to read into that random location. The operating system wisely told you that you can't do that.

Comment: In the future you might want to wait a little while before accepting answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
char word [256] ; // or something
```

Better yet

```
std::string word ;


cout << word.length () ;
```

Comment: But "char* word" and "char word[256]" should be the same thing, apart from the latter being limited to 255 elements excluding '\0'.

Comment: char word [256] ; creates a pointer to a buffer containing 256 bytes. char *word ; creates a pointer to nothing (until assigned).

Comment: So does the "cin >> word;" not assign it?

Comment: @user2871213 No, it does not. This really isn't the place for a tutorial.

Comment: However, note that IF you use a std::string, the class DOES automatically allocates the buffer for you.

Comment: @user3344003, `char word[256];` creates an array of 256 bytes, it does not create a pointer

Comment: How is word different in char *const word ; and int char word [256] ; other than the buffer allocation and sizeof ()???

Comment: There's no pointer in `char word[256]` and there is a pointer in `char *word` .. that's a big difference

Answer (score 1):

In your code "word" is just a pointer. If you mean to write something directly into a pointer, first you must assign a valid memory address to it. If it is not important for you that "word" is a pointer then a char array will suffice.